# Create useful Data Extension via Filter Activity in

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I am creating a simple happy birthday email sending automation.

However I am having an issue with the Filter Activity in Automation Studio.

I am unable to configure the Filter Activity to create a useful data extension. To be clear I can create the data extension but have no ability to control where it is made, and it is defaulting to creating the resulting DE in the Synchronised Data Extension folder.

[image: Create New Filter Activity]

This means I cannot use it as the target for either the email send activity nor Journey Builder.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or how this simple goal can be achieved!

Kind Regards

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are making an automation to filter from synchronised data extension.`That is the reason it will land into synchronised data extension.

If you want to do one time filter and send a one time email then you can filter directly by going into the synchronised data extension and select the folder to create a filtered data extension. But if you are using automated filter data definition then it will land always into synchronised data extension folder. You can't move the filtered DE.

I would suggest you to create a data extension and use SQL query to populate the values and automate it.

```
Select attribute1,attribute2
from synchronised DE
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Naveen, thanks for your input, and correct the Filter is running on a Synchronised Data Extension. I need a simple solution I can teach my clients and there is no technical reason it can't be done except perhaps a gap in the platform design/features. But I believe that this use case has been done many times before and I think the platform includes the ability to do this without requiring SQL.

Comment: Hello @Foweyboy, it is how it has been designed. since synchronise data extension will keep syncing every 15 mins or so that's the reason we can't automate the filter. We need to use SQL query to automate initially and post that you can use filter on data extensions. If you want to avoid SQL query then you can use 3rd party app exchange -DESelect , here you can drag and drop and create segments.

Comment: Hi Naveen, thanks for your input but this just confirmed what I was unfortunately concluding myself - another product gap. Oh well, I'm sure the dev team have it somewhere on their list but I'm not holding my breath!